# Java , PowerMock -- Mock Response based on HttpPost request body

Tags: java, http, mockito, http-post, powermock

I have multiple HttpPost requests like the one shown below:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(searchURL);
    httpPost.setEntity(...);
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = response -> {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        return httpEntity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity) : null;
    };
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

} catch()...
```

For testing these classes, I am mocking the HttpPost requests as under:

```
when(HttpClients.createDefault()).thenReturn(client);
when(response.getEntity()).thenReturn(entity);
whenNew(HttpPost.class).withArguments(url).thenReturn(httpPostSearchOrg);
when(client.execute(same(httpPostSearchOrg), any(ResponseHandler.class)))
                    .thenReturn(JSON_STRING);
```

Now with this test approach, I can mock only one response for POST call to the url. 
**Is it possible to mock multiple responses based on POST request body(ie. based on the request entity)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use an ArgumentCaptor and an Answer:

```
ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity> requestEntity = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpEntity.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(httpPostSearchOrg).setEntity(requestEntity.capture());
when(client.execute(same(httpPostSearchOrg), any(ResponseHandler.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            if (matchesEntityToReturnResponse1(requestEntity.getValue())) {
                return "RESPONSE1";
            } else {
                return "RESPONSE2";
            }
        }
    });
```